# filter NSArray with NSDictionary by int value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have the following NSArray:

```
(
        {
        establecimiento = 15;
        internet = 500;
    },
        {
        establecimiento = 0;
        internet = 1024;
    },
        {
        establecimiento = 24;
        internet = 300;
    }
)
```

And I need to filter the array for `establecimiento < 10`.

I'm trying this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"establecimiento = %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.establecimientoFiltro]];
```

where `self.establecimientoFiltro` is an int with value: 10

But I have as result an empty array.

Hope to be clear with my question and thank you in advance for your answers.

Regards,
Victor

Comment: Why are you using "=" if you want <10?

Comment: @user3175572 Check my answer below for a flexible output.

Comment: And it's unnecessary to convert your number to NSNumber -- you can use the number directly with `%d`.

Comment: Look at the answer below & let me know, if that confuses you. Ok

Comment: You just need to define the proper condition inside predicate format

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate checks to see if the value is equal to ten, not less than ten. You receive an empty array because that you provided us with does not contain a dictionary where the `establecimiento` key returns a value of 10.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"establecimiento < 10"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `blocks` with `Predicate` to achieve this.

Let's assume your array is in `myArray`. Now make a predicate with range of your choice. As of now, you want it to be less than 10 for `establecimientoFiltro`.

```
NSPredicate *keyPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  obj, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSRange myRange = NSMakeRange (0, 9);
    NSInteger rangeKey = [[obj valueForKey:@"establecimientoFiltro"]integerValue];
    if (NSLocationInRange(rangeKey, myRange)) {
        // found
        return YES;
    } else {
        // not found
        return NO;
    }
}];

NSArray *filterArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:keyPred];
NSLog(@"%@", filterArray);
```

You get your result filtered in the `filteredArray`.

Hope that is the efficient most & helpful to you.